# TraceDebugging Eating up all my Hard Disk Space

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate where came to know my all hard disk space is reducing day by day.  Then got into a folder Program Data\Visual Studio\10\TraceDebugging Where it used almost 116 Gb of my space. I dont know how to get rid of it and kinda skeptical removing manually. If anybody has faced this before or know the safest way to turn off or remove this files. Please help me with that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just delete the files there.  This was fixed in SP1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything I'm finding on the internet seems to say that these files are perfectly safe to delete.  There was a bug in Visual Studio 2010 that was not cleaning up these files.  A later service pack fixed the cleanup code.

You should install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 to correct the issue in the future.  The files are safe to delete manually.

A Link to SP1:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691